# Setting Up React Native in VSCODE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, visual-studio, expo

Hi there I'm a high school senior and for our final project we need to use an API and create a app fetching data from the API till now I learned the basics on react native from my class and we used the courses (CodeHS) online built in react native editor thats powered with expo to view our projects online but I've never used VSCodes and for the project turns out the students us have to learn how to use and implement API's so I was going to ask no project help but if someone can get me help on how to setup Visual Studio because the setup is so hard and I have to download so much for VS with react and people have like a phone emulator next to their program to see the output and I don't know how to do that and just need help on how to setup VSCode and I am not using project help!!! Thank you and have a great day

Didn't try too much the steps just a bit hard

Comment: are you using mac or windows ?

Comment: I think it will help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LqLh3Iizr74

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.